# How to enable compile error for missing return statement with Android NDK

Tags: gcc, android-ndk, compiler-errors

Using the Android NDK, I have a native method that returns a jobject -- except I forgot the return statement.  Unfortunately, this compiled without a warning, and only gave me a segfault at 0xdeadd00d when I tried to run it.

While I've been working primarily in Java recently so the error message in my head is "missing return statement", I believe the gcc error message is "control reaches end of non-void function".

I'd like to turn that warning on, and turn it into an error.  How do I do that?  (Simply using `-Wall -Werror` isn't an option, due to the existing codebase I am compiling against.)

Answer (score 8):

After some time with the GCC manpage and several rebuilds, I've figured out that the commandline flag to add is `-Werror=return-type`.  Append that to the LOCAL_CFLAGS in your Android.mk.

Also, to find out just what a given error type is called, you can turn on -Wall and check the compiler output; after the warning, it displays the relevant -W flag.

```
error: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
```

To turn that warning on individually, use the flag exactly as it appears in the brackets there.  To turn it on as an error, insert "error=" immediately after the -W, as in `-Werror=return-type`.